# in android studio 3.0 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzfdf.class

Comment: Try to **clean** and **build** your project.